# Vue bind style dynamic backgroundImage with parameter using asset

Tags: vue.js, webpack, data-binding, axios, vuex

I'm trying to bind background images dynamically but there seems to be trouble compiling the assets. What's weird is that it works but no at the same time.
[image: vue_dynamic_image_err_compile]

I've tried various solutions from SO and nothing get rids of the compilation error (which still compile based on the image above):

- [Vue.js dynamic images not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40491506/vue-js-dynamic-images-not-working)
- [VueJS v-bind:style for background-image: url()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40666716/vuejs-v-bindstyle-for-background-image-url)
- [Vue.js data-bind style backgroundImage not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35242272/vue-js-data-bind-style-backgroundimage-not-working)
- [reference assets with generated style data bind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51643887/reference-assets-with-generated-style-data-bind)
- [Vue dynamic background image inline component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60859602/vue-dynamic-background-image-inline-component)

## How The Project is Set Up

Laravel Sanctum as the backend, Vue SPA for the frontend and utilising Axios for communications.

## Topic.vue Component

```
<div
    v-for="topic in topics"
    :key="topic.id"
    class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 mb-4 d-flex justify-content-center"
>
    <div
        class="card-topic d-flex align-items-end"
        :style="inlineBgImage(topic.src)"
    >
        <div class="card-topic__button py-3 text-center w-100">
            <a href class="card-topic__link">{{ topic.title }}</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

## Script in Topic.vue

```
<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex'

export default {
    computed: {
        ...mapState('topic', ['topics']),
    },
    created() {
        this.$store.dispatch('topic/fetchTopics')
    },
    methods: {
        inlineBgImage(src) {
            let bgImage = require('@/assets' + src)

            return {
                backgroundImage: `url("${bgImage}")`,
            }
        },
    },
}
</script>
```

In the `inlineBgImage(src)` methods, the background-image is successfully applied if the require is hardcoded i.e. `let bgImage = require('@/assets/img/topic/myself.jpg')`. Once I used the `src` value, it broked but still works(Failed to compile. page appear)

## Assets

Below is the asset folder structure

[image]

All SCSS files are imported to `app.scss` which are then imported to `main.js`

### _variables.scss

[image]

The "undefined variable" *does* exist

### app.scss

This is how I import the `_variable.scss` file in `app.scss`; `@import 'variables.scss';`. The import comes first before other files.
[image]

I've also tried:

- `@import 'variables';`
- `@import '_variables';`
- `@import '_variables.scss';`

It still gives out errors.

## Error Details in Terminal

I want to reiterate that these errors does not appear if I hardcode the `bgImage` e.g. `require('@/assets/img/topic/myself.jpg')`. I don't understand how these changes affect the compiler.

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 6 errors                                                                                                  12:37:58 PM
 error  in ./src/assets/scss/card.scss

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Undefined variable.
   ╷
16 │     background-color: $dark-blue;
   │                       ^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
  src\assets\scss\card.scss 16:23  root stylesheet

 @ ./src/assets/scss/card.scss 4:14-233 14:3-18:5 15:22-241
 @ ./src sync ^\.\/assets.*$
 @ ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/views/Topic.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./src/views/Topic.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./src/views/Topic.vue
 @ ./src/router/index.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.100.14:8080&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js

 error  in ./src/assets/scss/search.scss

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Undefined variable.
   ╷
27 │     color: $blue;
   │            ^^^^^
   ╵
  src\assets\scss\search.scss 27:12  root stylesheet

 @ ./src/assets/scss/search.scss 4:14-235 14:3-18:5 15:22-243
 @ ./src sync ^\.\/assets.*$
 @ ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/views/Topic.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./src/views/Topic.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./src/views/Topic.vue
 @ ./src/router/index.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.100.14:8080&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js

 error  in ./src/assets/scss/image.scss

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Undefined variable.
   ╷
33 │     color: $white;
   │            ^^^^^^
   ╵
  src\assets\scss\image.scss 33:12  root stylesheet

 @ ./src/assets/scss/image.scss 4:14-234 14:3-18:5 15:22-242
 @ ./src sync ^\.\/assets.*$
 @ ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/views/Topic.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./src/views/Topic.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./src/views/Topic.vue
 @ ./src/router/index.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.100.14:8080&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js

 error  in ./src/assets/scss/button.scss

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Undefined variable.
  ╷
2 │     color: $light-blue;
  │            ^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  src\assets\scss\button.scss 2:12  root stylesheet

 @ ./src/assets/scss/button.scss 4:14-235 14:3-18:5 15:22-243
 @ ./src sync ^\.\/assets.*$
 @ ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/views/Topic.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./src/views/Topic.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./src/views/Topic.vue
 @ ./src/router/index.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.100.14:8080&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js

 error  in ./src/assets/scss/header.scss

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Undefined variable.
  ╷
4 │     background-color: $dark-blue;
  │                       ^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  src\assets\scss\header.scss 4:23  root stylesheet

 @ ./src/assets/scss/header.scss 4:14-235 14:3-18:5 15:22-243
 @ ./src sync ^\.\/assets.*$
 @ ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/views/Topic.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./src/views/Topic.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./src/views/Topic.vue
 @ ./src/router/index.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.100.14:8080&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js

 error  in ./src/assets/scss/nav.scss

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Undefined variable.
  ╷
6 │     color: $light-blue;
  │            ^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  src\assets\scss\nav.scss 6:12  root stylesheet

 @ ./src/assets/scss/nav.scss 4:14-232 14:3-18:5 15:22-240
 @ ./src sync ^\.\/assets.*$
 @ ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/views/Topic.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./src/views/Topic.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./src/views/Topic.vue
 @ ./src/router/index.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.100.14:8080&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js
```

## Other Details

The `topic.src` from `v-for="topic in topics"` will yield a String, for e.g. `/img/topic/myself.jpg`.

Comment: Yes, it does and as I've mentioned, hardcoding it works but not dynamically. @tony19 I've edited the post showing that it is defined

Comment: Wouldn't `let bgImage = require('@/assets/img/topic/myself.jpg')` be equivalent to `let bgImage = require('@/assets' + src)` given that `src` equals to `/img/topic/myself.jpg`?

Comment: I don't even know how it breaks the styling. That's why I'm asking for help. I would appreciate it if you could guide me on this issue.

Comment: It seems like you didn't `@import` the `_variables.scss` right before using them.

Comment: Hey, I've tried various statement after you mentioned that. You can see from the edit I've made. How should I import it @YomS.?

Comment: That being imported foremost should normally work, what's the error pertaining to that specifically?

Comment: All I know is that the error is caused by dynamically requiring assets; `require('@/assets' + src)`. I don't know any more from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
inlineBgImage(src) {
    let fileExt = src.substring(src.lastIndexOf('.'))

    src = src.replace('/img/', '')
    src = src.replace(fileExt, '')

    let bgImage = require('@/assets/img/' + src + fileExt)

    return {
        backgroundImage: `url("${bgImage}")`,
    }
}
```

Kudos to skirtle for giving a solution at [forum.vuejs.org](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vue-bind-style-dynamic-backgroundimage-with-parameter-using-asset/102383/2?u=afiqrosli). As skirtle mentioned, **Webpack handles expression and fixed string parameter differently**. I did change the solution a bit in case future files have different file extension. You see skirtle original answer and explanation there.